# Code not retrieving/displaying date from Parse.com in a UILabel

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to retrieve the updatedAt section of a parse object and displaying it as a label. I have created a date formatter yet when I convert it to a string it just becomes a null value. Here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
[super viewDidLoad];

PFQuery *BizarroTime = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Bizarro"];
[BizarroTime getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"MkoIkCBMdP" block:^(PFObject *Bizarro, NSError *error) {
    NSDate *BizarroDate = Bizarro[@"updatedAt"];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd 'at' HH:mm"];
    self.BizarroUpdatedAt.text = [df stringFromDate:BizarroDate];
}];
}
```

Any help with this would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting the proper NSDate back before you attempt to format it as a string?

Comment: I am not sure, all that I know is that the date in parse's data browser is 2014-08-03T18:15:35.648Z under the updatedAt column which has type 'Date'

Comment: Try printing the NSDate.

Comment: Not sure if it actually reaching the app, how should I check?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", BizarroDate);

Comment: That just shows a null value.

Comment: I added  NSLog(@"Date is %@",BizarroDate);  and the console returns "Date is (null)"

Comment: OK, so you must have made a mistake somewhere. Some suggestions: (1) Double check the object ID "MkoIkCBMdP", (2) log the block's `error`. P.S. What happens when you trying printing the object? Ex. `NSLog(@"%@", Bizarro);`

Comment: Here is what the console says when i log the error and print the object: 2014-08-03 17:38:30.646 Great Adventure Wait Times[9250:607] Date is (null)
2014-08-03 17:38:30.647 Great Adventure Wait Times[9250:607] Bizarro is <Bizarro:MkoIkCBMdP:(null)> {
    waitTime = 60;
}
2014-08-03 17:38:30.647 Great Adventure Wait Times[9250:607] (null)

Comment: The updated date is accessed via a method, not like a regular property. See my answer below.

Comment: @woakley5 OK, so it is returning an object with a waitTime of 60. Take @danh's suggestion and try replacing `Bizarro[@"updatedAt"];` with `[Bizarro updatedAt];`

Answer (score 2):

To make danh's message more concise for future answer-seekers, the `updatedAt` field of a Parse `PFObject* object` cannot be accessed as if it's a value in the object's dictionary, ex.:

```
object[@"updatedAt"];
```

But must instead be accessed using Parse's `updatedAt` method:

```
[object updatedAt];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the returned object is non-nil.  If there is an object, the way to get it's updated date is via the `PFObject` method called `updatedAt` ...

```
[BizarroTime getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"MkoIkCBMdP" block:^(PFObject *Bizarro, NSError *error) {
    if (Bizarro) {
        NSDate *BizarroDate = [Bizarro updatedAt];
        // format as you have it
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: That still returns nill